# Creating a master hook for a form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

Suppose I have a react component that is essentially a form with a submit button that makes a post request to update a database table `onSubmit`. The post request requires the past data to be in a json format like this:

```
contactData = {"Name": "myName", "Email": "abc@gmail.com", "Phone": "999-999-9999"}
```

Essentially, I want to create a `contactData` hook that updates "Name", "Email", and "Phone" everytime the `onChange` event is fired. Its the structure of the hook that I need help with.
I have already tried to do this, but it doesn't work. The `postData` variable is empty when the `axios` request is called. How can I get this to work? Is there a way to get all the input data from the form at one time (after its been populated)?:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";

export default function AddContactForm() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [phone, set] = useState("");

    //combined data object
    const postData = {
       name,
       email,
       phone
    }

    async function createUser(contactData) {
        await axios.post(config.apiURL + `/add_update_user/add_user`, { contactData })
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
        })
    }
 
    const myChangeHandler = (event) => {
        let nam = event.target.name;
        let val = event.target.value;
        if (nam === 'contact_name') {
          setName(val);
        } else if (nam === 'email') {
          setEmail(val);
        } else if (nam === 'phone') {
          setPhone(val);
        }
    }
   
    function mySubmitHandler(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log({ postData });
        createUser({ postData });
    }

    return(
        <div className="container all-center">
          <div className="card text-center" style={{ background: "#54c5f1" }}>
            <form onSubmit={mySubmitHandler}>
              <h3 style={{ textDecoration: "underline" }}>Complete the Contact Information and hit submit:</h3>
              <label>Contact Name</label>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='name'
                id='name'
                onChange={myChangeHandler}
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
              />
              <label>Email Address</label>
              <input
                 type='text'
                 name='email'
                 id='email'
                 onChange={myChangeHandler}
                 style={{ width: "100%" }}
              />
              <label>Phone Number</label>
              <input
                 type='text'
                 name='phone'
                 id='phone'
                 onChange={myChangeHandler}
                 style={{ width: "100%" }}
              />
              <button className="btn btn-primary"
               type='submit' id='addContactBtn'>Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You have to assign the hooks as the value to these elements

Comment: So, like this: `const postData = { "name":  name,  "email":  email, "phone": phone }` ?

Comment: No, to your Html elements `value={name}`.

Comment: But I am using hooks here; I want to use the value to setHookValue. Can you provide an example?